# How to save query params in Server component (next js 13 app router)

Tags: reactjs, next.js13, nextjs-dynamic-routing, app-router

In Next js 13 app router

In server componets search paramaters are required to navigate between Page A and Page B
example:
Page A url (http://localhost:3000/order-details?order-id=10)
Page B url ( (http://localhost:3000/order-status)

after entering to Page A, You can navigate to Page B. The problem here is how to navigate back to Page A from Page B. Is there any way that i can store query parameters of Page A at server side. ( In client component this can be achieved using Context API or session Storage) How to do it at server side??

I have asked a question regrading next js 13 server side components and expecting answer for that

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use [cookies](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/cookies) to persist data between pages on the server.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of cookies. I have used Query parameters sending order-id to both the pages, so I can grab it using searchParams. Cookies will work but I have similar cases where lots of data is needed to store.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).